# Procedure or function 'Test' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to understanding stored procedures. I am dealing with one similar to this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Test]
(
@ID int,
@month int,
@Low int,
@standard float = 0
)
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Table1] WHERE ID = @ID AND 
month = @month AND TYPE = 'S' AND TYPEID = @Low)
BEGIN
UPDATE [Table1] SET 
    Add = @standard
    WHERE ID = @ID AND month = @month AND TYPE = 'S' AND TYPEID = @Low
END
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [Table1] (ID, month, Add, TYPE, TYPEID) 
    VALUES (@ID, @month, @standard, 'S', @Low)
END
GO
```

Which runs from this table:

```
ID     Month    Add    Type    TypeID
333    feb      0       T        111
333    feb      4       S        111
333    feb      -2      K        111
```

But i receive this error:

**'Procedure or function 'Test' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied.'**

When i try and execute the procedure

Can someone advise me on whats going on here with the error here and what i can do to fix it? I have included ID so im not quite sure why that is creating an error. thanks

I call the procedure like this:

```
USE [DB1]
GO
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [Test]
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Comment: How do you call your stored procedure?

Comment: So why aren't you calling the procedure *with parameters*? The error message is self explanatory - the procedure takes four parameters, but you haven't supplied any (it only reports the error the first time it happens, which is when it expects `@ID`).

Comment: `EXEC    @return_value = [Test]`  Where are parameters?

Comment: @lad2025 this is just how i found the procedure. I dont really know enough about them so i am trying to understand

Comment: `EXEC @return_value = [Test] @id = ?, @month = ?, @low=?, @standard=?;` And exchange ? with actual value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this: In SQL Server Management Studio, in the Object Explorer pane, right click on your stored procedure and choose "Script Stored Procedure as ->", "EXECUTE To ->", and then "New Query Editor Window".  This will build a SQL statement for you that will properly execute your stored procedure when supplied with the proper parameter values.